# Twitter bootstrap - Navbar with tabs don't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add tabs into `.navbar` but `.tab-content` doesn't show below tabs but beside it.
When I remove `.navbar` class tabs works fine (content is below tabs), so there is some problem with `.navbar` class. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Here is code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <a class="brand" href="/system/default/">Home</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse subnav-collapse">
     <div id="snippet--mainMenu">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li class=""><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Analyze</a></li>
       <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li class=""><a href="/system/search/" >Search</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" style="padding-bottom: 9px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
       <ul> 
        <li style="display: inline;list-style-type: none;"><a href="/system/analyze/builder">Builder</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;list-style-type: none;"><a href="/system/analyze/history">History</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;list-style-type: none;"><a href="/system/analyze/optimize">Optimize</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
       <ul> 
        <li style="display: inline;list-style-type: none;"><a href="/system/portfolio/list">Table List</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;list-style-type: none;"><a href="/system/portfolio/watchlist">Watchlist</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;list-style-type: none;"><a href="/system/portfolio/temporary">Temporary</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>                    
   <div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> User<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="/system/user/">Profile</a></li>
     <li class="divider"></li>
     <li><a href="/system/default/logout">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>                    
  </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->                                 
 </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two different things. Navbar and tabs are not compatible. You can't include `.nav-tabs` inside a `.navbar`, not to mention including the `.tab-panes`.
You can get a navigation bar with

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can get a tabbed navigation with

```
<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But you cant mix this code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with a bit of annoying effort, you CAN.

Create your navbar & your tabbable as 2 distinct things.  Hide the nav.nav-tabs.  Then attach scripts to the navbar entries to show the appropriate tab and (for completeness) highlight the selected navbar entry (stuff Bootstrap would do for a normal navbar).

Answer (score 0):

Solution is `style="clear: both;"` for `.tab-content`

Comment: That doesn't change anything, that code, as you posted, is wrong http://jsfiddle.net/simbirsk/ZvYeG/